# kotlin String::replace removing escape sequences?

Tags: regex, kotlin, escaping

I'm trying some string manipulation using regex's, but I'm not getting the expected output

```
var myString = "/api/<user_id:int>/"
myString.replace(Regex("<user_id:int>"), "(\\d+)")
```

this should give me something like `/api/(\d+)/` but instead I get `/api/(d+)/`

However if I create an escaped string directly like `var a = "\d+"`
I get the correct output `\d+` (that I can further use to create a regex Pattern)
is this due to the way `String::replace` works?
if so, isn't this a bug, why is it removing my escape sequences?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make the replace a literal string, use:

```
myString.replace(Regex("<user_id:int>"), Regex.escapeReplacement("(\\d+)"))
```

For details, this is what kotlin [Regex.replace](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.30/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/text/regex/Regex.kt#L150) is doing:

```
  Pattern nativePattern = Pattern.compile("<user_id:int>");
  String m = nativePattern.matcher("/api/<user_id:int>/").replaceAll("(\\d+)");

  -> m = (d+)
```

From [Matcher.replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String)) javadoc:

> Note that backslashes () and dollar signs ($) in the replacement
>   string may cause the results to be different than if it were being
>   treated as a literal replacement string. Dollar signs may be treated
>   as references to captured subsequences as described above, and
>   backslashes are used to escape literal characters in the replacement
>   string.

The call to Regex.escapeReplacement above does exactly that, turning `(\\d+)` to `(\\\\d+)`

Answer (score 4):

You are using a [`.replace`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html) overload that takes a regex as the first argument, thus, the second argument is parsed as a regex replacement pattern. Inside a regex replacement pattern, a `\` char is special, it may escape a dollar symbol to be treated as a literal dollar sign. So, the literal backslash inside regex replacement patterns should be doubled.

You might use

```
myString.replace(Regex("<user_id:int>"), """(\\d+)""")
```

Whenever you have to search and replace with a regex and your replacement pattern is a dynamic value, you should use [`Regex.escapeReplacement`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/escape-replacement.html) (see [GUIDO's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49074799/3832970)).

However, you are replacing a literal value with another literal value, you do not have to use a regex here:

```
myString.replace("<user_id:int>", """(\d+)""")
```

See [this Kotlin demo](http://rextester.com/UPYQ55927) yielding `/api/(\d+)/`.

Note the use of raw string literals where a backslash is parsed as a literal backslash.

Answer (score -1):

The replacement as the regex engine see's it is interpolated as a double quoted string.
This is true with every regex engine.

This is to distinguish control codes, like tab newline or carriage return.

Nothing special here.

So the replacement as the engine wants to see it is `(\\d+)`.

The *language* interpolates the same.

Final result `repl_str = "(\\\\d+)"`

Comment: For future readers of this question - There is no _Company_ line associated with the answer. Anybody posting links to language docs, simply don't understand regular expressions.

Comment: In Kotlin, the answer is `repl_str = """(\d+)"""`, or `repl_str = "(\\d+)"`, certainly not `repl_str = "(\\\\d+)"`